# PHP place <p> around string not around <div>

Tags: php, html, css, str-replace

Let's say I post the following:

> Love this tweet
>   https://twitter.com/yarratrams/status/489336308423491584

then the script below will run the following part of the code below:

```
$string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string).$stats->html;
```

It will then end up like the following

```
Love this tweet <a href="https://twitter.com/yarratrams/status/489336308423491584" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">https://twitter.com/yarratrams/status/489336308423491584</a><iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-tweet twitter-tweet-rendered" title="Embedded Tweet" height="186" style="display: block; max-width: 99%; min-width: 220px; padding: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; margin: 10px 0px; border-color: rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(221, 221, 221) rgb(187, 187, 187); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px; position: static; visibility: visible; width: 500px;"></iframe>
<script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I want to encase the following part in `<p></p>`:

> Love this tweet https://twitter.com/yarratrams/status/489336308423491584

so the end result should look like this

```
<p>Love this tweet <a href="https://twitter.com/yarratrams/status/489336308423491584" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">https://twitter.com/yarratrams/status/489336308423491584</a></p><iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-tweet twitter-tweet-rendered" title="Embedded Tweet" height="186" style="display: block; max-width: 99%; min-width: 220px; padding: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; margin: 10px 0px; border-color: rgb(238, 238, 238) rgb(221, 221, 221) rgb(187, 187, 187); border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px; position: static; visibility: visible; width: 500px;"></iframe>
<script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>              </div>
```

I currently do the following when someone post a comment and includes a tweet, YouTube or Vimeo link or upload an image to our Amazon server:

```
function autolink($string,$uid = null){
    // force http: on www.
    $string = str_ireplace( "twitter.com", "http://twitter.com", $string );
     $string = str_ireplace( "http://twitter.comhttp://twitter.com", "http://twitter.com", $string );
    $string = str_ireplace( "www.", "http://", $string );
    $string = str_ireplace( "http://http://", "http://", $string );
    // eliminate duplicates after force
    $string = str_ireplace( "http://http://www.", "http://", $string );
    $string = str_ireplace( "https://http://www.", "https://", $string );

    // The Regular Expression filter
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
    // Check if there is a url in the text

    $m = preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $string, $match); 

    if ($m) { 
        $links=$match[0]; 
        for ($j=0;$j<$m;$j++) { 

            if(substr($links[$j], 0, 14) == 'http://youtube'){

            $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string).'<div class="embed-container"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.substr($links[$j], -11).'" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';

            }
            elseif(substr($links[$j], 0, 12) == 'http://vimeo'){

            $status = file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=".$links[$j]);
            $vim = json_decode($status);
            $embed = preg_replace(array('/width="\d+"/i', '/height="\d+"/i'),array('', ''),$vim->html);
            //$string = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url=".$links[$j];
            $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string)."<div class='embed-container'>".$embed."</div>";

            }
            elseif(substr($links[$j], 0,16) == 'http://au.images')
            {

            $string=str_replace($links[$j],null,$string).'<div class="imgover"><a href="'.$links[$j].'" data-rel="shadowbox['.rand(0,57475676).']"><img alt="'.$links[$j].'" src="'.$links[$j].'"></a></div>';

            }
            elseif(substr($links[$j], 0,16) == 'http://instagram')
            {
                http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/V8UMy0LjpX/
                $status = file_get_contents("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=".$links[$j]);
                $stats = json_decode($status);
            //$string = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url=".$links[$j];
            if(isset($stats->errors))
            {

            }
            else
            $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string).'</p><div class="imgover"><a href="'.$stats->url.'" data-rel="shadowbox['.rand(0,57475676).']"><img  alt="'.$links[$j].'" src="'.$stats->url.'" ></a></div>';


            }
            elseif(substr($links[$j], 0, 15) == 'https://twitter'){

            $status = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url=".$links[$j]);
            $stats = json_decode($status);
            //$string = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url=".$links[$j];
            if(isset($stats->errors))
            {

            }
            else
            $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string).$stats->html;

            }
            else{
            $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string);
            } 
        } 
    }
```

However my issue is I want to place a `<p></p>` around the string that was not changed - as when I put padding on the outer div it seems to move all the internal DIV and this is one way of fixing it is by placing the `<p></p>` just to the text before the modified string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@thx to Daniel Sirakoff
this is the correct code after playing with the code he commented

```
   $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>','<p>'.$string.'</p>').'<div class="twitterembed">'.$stats->html.'</div>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can just concatenate like `echo '<p>'.$string.'</p>';`

Comment: No i cant it is not valid html5 standard you can have a div inside a p

Comment: Then I really don't understand your question

Comment: So you want to wrap the paragraph in a div ?

Comment: I have added how it should look after it includes the p

Comment: Does this help `$string=str_replace($links[$j],'<p><a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a></p>',$string).$stats->html;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57389/discussion-between-daniel-sirakoff-and-russellharrower).

Comment: That only places it around the <a> link not the next

Comment: Is the 'Love this tweet' generated with php or in the html

Comment: the user types it like they would in twitter